# Set Grid.Column and Grid.Row for control inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm writing an application in WPF. I have custom Grid control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Controls.DynamicGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App.Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid x:Name="BaseGrid"/>
</UserControl>
```

```
namespace App.Controls
{
    public partial class DynamicGrid : UserControl
    {
        #region PROPERTIES

        private static DependencyProperty ColumnsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Columns", typeof(int), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public int Columns
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(ColumnsProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColumnsProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty RowsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Rows", typeof(int), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public int Rows
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(RowsProperty);
            set => SetValue(RowsProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeadersSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public IEnumerable ColumnHeadersSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ColumnHeadersSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColumnHeadersSourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty RowHeadersSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RowHeadersSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public IEnumerable RowHeadersSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(RowHeadersSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(RowHeadersSourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get => (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty ColumnHeadersTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnHeadersTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public DataTemplate ColumnHeadersTemplate
        {
            get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ColumnHeadersTemplateProperty);
            set => SetValue(ColumnHeadersTemplateProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty RowHeadersTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RowHeadersTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public DataTemplate RowHeadersTemplate
        {
            get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(RowHeadersTemplateProperty);
            set => SetValue(RowHeadersTemplateProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
        {
            get => (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty CellBorderThicknessProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CellBorderThickness", typeof(Thickness), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness(0), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public Thickness CellBorderThickness
        {
            get => (Thickness)GetValue(CellBorderThicknessProperty);
            set => SetValue(CellBorderThicknessProperty, value);
        }

        private static DependencyProperty CellBorderBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("CellBorderBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Black, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChanged)));
        public Brush CellBorderBrush
        {
            get => (Brush)GetValue(CellBorderBrushProperty);
            set => SetValue(CellBorderBrushProperty, value);
        }

        #endregion



        #region CONSTRUCTORS

        public DynamicGrid()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #endregion



        #region PRIVATE METHODS

        private void Refresh()
        {
            BaseGrid.Children.Clear();
            BaseGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
            BaseGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();

            if (Columns != 0 && Rows != 0)
            {
                bool columnHeaders = ColumnHeadersSource != null && ColumnHeadersSource.Cast<object>().Count() > 0;
                int columnHeadersInt = Convert.ToInt32(columnHeaders);
                bool rowHeaders = RowHeadersSource != null && RowHeadersSource.Cast<object>().Count() > 0;
                int rowHeadersInt = Convert.ToInt32(rowHeaders);

                if (columnHeaders) 
                {
                    BaseGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

                    for (int column = columnHeadersInt; column < Columns + columnHeadersInt; column++)
                    {
                        Border border = new Border()
                        {
                            BorderBrush = CellBorderBrush,
                            BorderThickness = CellBorderThickness,
                        };
                        Grid.SetColumn(border, column);
                        Grid.SetRow(border, 0);
                        BaseGrid.Children.Add(border);

                        if (ColumnHeadersSource.Cast<object>().Count() > column - 1)
                        {
                            object columnHeaderItem = ColumnHeadersSource.Cast<object>().ElementAt(column - 1);
                            FrameworkElement control;
                            if (ColumnHeadersTemplate is not null)
                            {
                                control = ColumnHeadersTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
                                control.DataContext = columnHeaderItem;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                control = new Label()
                                {
                                    Content = columnHeaderItem.ToString()
                                };
                            }
                            border.Child = control;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (rowHeaders)
                {
                    BaseGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());

                    for (int row = rowHeadersInt; row < Rows + rowHeadersInt; row++)
                    {
                        Border border = new Border()
                        {
                            BorderBrush = CellBorderBrush,
                            BorderThickness = CellBorderThickness,
                        };
                        Grid.SetColumn(border, 0);
                        Grid.SetRow(border, row);
                        BaseGrid.Children.Add(border);

                        if (RowHeadersSource.Cast<object>().Count() > row - 1)
                        {
                            object rowHeaderItem = RowHeadersSource.Cast<object>().ElementAt(row - 1);
                            FrameworkElement control;
                            if (RowHeadersTemplate is not null)
                            {
                                control = RowHeadersTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
                                control.DataContext = rowHeaderItem;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                control = new Label()
                                {
                                    Content = rowHeaderItem.ToString()
                                };
                            }
                            border.Child = control;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for (int _ = 0 ; _ < Rows; _++)
                {
                    BaseGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
                }
                for (int _ = 0; _ < Columns; _++)
                {
                    BaseGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
                }

                Border[,] borderMatrix = new Border[Rows, Columns];
                for (int row = columnHeadersInt; row < Rows + columnHeadersInt; row++)
                {
                    for (int column = rowHeadersInt; column < Columns + rowHeadersInt; column++)
                    {
                        Border border = new Border()
                        {
                            BorderBrush = CellBorderBrush,
                            BorderThickness = CellBorderThickness,
                        };
                        Grid.SetColumn(border, column);
                        Grid.SetRow(border, row);
                        BaseGrid.Children.Add(border);
                        borderMatrix[row - columnHeadersInt, column - rowHeadersInt] = border;
                    }
                }

                if (ItemsSource is not null)
                {
                    foreach (object item in ItemsSource.Cast<object>())
                    {
                        FrameworkElement control;
                        if (ItemTemplate is not null)
                        {
                            control = ItemTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
                            control.DataContext = item;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            control = new Label()
                            {
                                Content = item.ToString()
                            };
                        }
                        borderMatrix[GetRow(control), GetColumn(control)].Child = control;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) => ((DynamicGrid)obj).Refresh();

        #endregion



        #region COLUMN/ROW SET/GET STATIC METHODS

        private static DependencyProperty ColumnProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Column", typeof(int), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));
        public static int GetColumn(UIElement element) => (int)element.GetValue(ColumnProperty);
        public static void SetColumn(UIElement element, int value) => element.SetValue(ColumnProperty, value);

        private static DependencyProperty RowProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Row", typeof(int), typeof(DynamicGrid), new PropertyMetadata(0));
        public static int GetRow(UIElement element) => (int)element.GetValue(RowProperty);
        public static void SetRow(UIElement element, int value) => element.SetValue(RowProperty, value);

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I use it in Window like that:

```
<c:DynamicGrid Grid.Column="0" 
               Columns="{Binding Columns.Count}" 
               Rows="{Binding Rows.Count}"
               ColumnHeadersSource="{Binding Columns}"
               RowHeadersSource="{Binding Rows}"
               ItemsSource="{Binding Test}"
               CellBorderThickness="1">
    <c:DynamicGrid.ColumnHeadersTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </c:DynamicGrid.ColumnHeadersTemplate>
    <c:DynamicGrid.RowHeadersTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </c:DynamicGrid.RowHeadersTemplate>
    <c:DynamicGrid.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Label}" c:DynamicGrid.Column="{Binding Column}" c:DynamicGrid.Row="{Binding Row}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </c:DynamicGrid.ItemTemplate>
</c:DynamicGrid>
```

Where Test is an ObservableCollection of objects of Cell class:

```
public class Cell
{
    public int Row { get; set; }
    public int Column { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that no matter what value the Row and Column properties have, all elements are placed in first row and first column

[image]

In this example "aaaaaaaaa" should be placed in the third row ("10:00 - 11:00") and the second column ("Tuesday")

```
Test.Add(new Cell()
{
    Row = 3,
    Column = 2,
    Label = "aaaaaaaaa"
});
```

Comment: Any reason not to use `DataGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot wrong with your current approach, since you're basically trying to reinvent `DataGrid` and `ContentPresenter`, all at the same time. Also, `Refresh` will be called too many times, for every property change, for no good reason.

But if you want to stick to it (which I don't recommend), and to answer your original question, the problem is in this line of code:

```
borderMatrix[GetRow(control), GetColumn(control)].Child = control;
```

When you set `DataContext` in code, property bindings on that control are not realized until the dispatcher has processed all data binding operations (or until the control is fully loaded). The workaround would be to wait for the data binding engine to do it's work, and then get the actual values of `c:DynamicGrid.Column` and `c:DynamicGrid.Row`, like so:

```
if (control.DataContext != null)
{
    Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(
        () => borderMatrix[GetRow(control), GetColumn(control)].Child = control,
        DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
}
```